# Google Reader API HTTP Response parsing (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, google-reader

Using the API, trying to get items in a specific feed returns this:

{“direction”:”ltr”,”id”:”feed/http://arstechnica.com/index.rssx”,”title”:”Ars Technica”,”description”:”The Art of Technology”,”self”:[{"href":"http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http://arstechnica.com/index.rssx?ot\u003d1273193172856169\u0026r\u003dn\u0026xt\u003duser/-/state/com.google/read\u0026n\u003d4\u0026ck\u003d1273193873\u0026client\u003diPadReader"}],”alternate”:[{"href":"http://arstechnica.com/index.php","type":"text/html"}],”updated”:1273193873,”items”:[]}

They look like key/value pairs but it’s plain text with UTF8 String encoding and won’t encode into a dictionary. I’m using Objective-C and I’m not sure where to go from here. So far I’ve been able to parse the XML response for unread items, but parsing the plain-text doesn’t look feasible. What is your practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [JSON markup](http://www.json.org/). You'll want to use a [JSON parser](http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c) for Objective-C.

Comment: I guess you're right.  I found some unofficial documentation that says even if you request XML it still gives you this.

Thanks for the link